# How to convert std::vector<byte> into hex string for output

Tags: android, c++

On Android as an input I have (as an example)

`std::vector<BYTE> input{15, 78, 76, 32, 20};`

I would like to visualize it as a string

`"0x0F 0x4E 0x4C 0x20 0x14"`

with `__android_log_print` function.

How would I do that?

Comment: You can loop through the `std::vector` writing each `BYTE` to a `std::ostringstream` using `operator<<` with the `std::hex`, `std::setw` and `std::setfill` manipulators, and then log the resulting `std::string` from the `std::ostringstream`

Comment: Thanks!

I tried that:
    std::ostringstream stream;
    for (std::vector<BYTE>::const_iterator it = message.begin(); it != message.end(); it++)
    {
        stream << "0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << (*it);
        stream << " ";
    }
    std::string result(stream.str());
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TEST", "Output:%s", result.c_str());

Here is the output
[TEST] Output:0x0 0x0N 0x0L 0x0  0x0 

If I view the output in a binary viewer, the bytes are correct.

Comment: @abalaev What is `BYTE`? I assumed `std::byte` since you used `byte` in the title. Did you try my example?

Comment: @abalaev you need to cast the value of `*it` to an (unsigned) integer before you give it to `operator<<`, because `operator<<` is overloaded to treat all 8-bit `(unsigned) char` values as text characters instead of as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

A straight forward approach would be to convert it to a `std::string` and use that with `__android_log_print`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string to_hex_string(const std::vector<std::byte>& v) {
    std::ostringstream os;

    if (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end()) {
        os << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << "0x" << std::setw(2)
           << static_cast<int>(*it);
           
        for (++it; it != v.end(); ++it) {
            os << " 0x" << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(*it);
        }
    }

    return os.str();
}
```

Usage:

```
int retval = __android_log_print(prio, tag, "%s",
                                 to_hex_string(the_vector).c_str());
```

---

If you are unsure about if `BYTE` is a `signed` or `unsigned` type, you could make the conversion to `int` in different ways depending on the signedness. For `signed` types, you need to first cast to an `unsigned char` before the cast to `int`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

std::string to_hex_string(const std::vector<BYTE>& v) {
    std::ostringstream os;

    auto conv = [] {
        if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<BYTE>) {
            return [](BYTE b) {
                return static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(b));
            };
        } else {
            return [](BYTE b) { return static_cast<int>(b); };
        }
    }();

    if (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end()) {
        os << std::hex << std::setfill('0')
           << "0x" << std::setw(2) << conv(*it);

        for (++it; it != v.end(); ++it) {
            os << " 0x" << std::setw(2) << conv(*it);
        }
    }

    return os.str();
}
```

... or just always do the double cast.

Comment: I would write the loop like this:

`os << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
  if (it != v.begin()) os << " ";
  os << "0x" << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(*it);
}`

Comment: @karttu Sure, that should produce the same result, but what would be the benefit of writing it like that?

Comment: Removes the need for the if() before for() and makes the code more readable (IMO).

Comment: @karttu Ok. I prefer to not have the `if` in every iteration of the loop or to invoke the stream manipulators if the vector is empty so I usually print one character before the known non-empty container and then the loop can iterate without extra conditions.

Comment: Makes sense. Then again, that test could have been taken before the call. Depends on the specification.

Comment: @karttu _"that test could have been taken before the call"_ - I never assume that I know anything about the input unless the function is only available as an internal/`private` function. This feels like a free function so I wouldn't want users to have to check. If they provide an empty `vector` they get an empty `string` back.

Comment: My final point is, it depends whether you are writing a library function for multiple users, or a helper function for yourself.

Comment: @karttu Yes, that was the point I was going for. If it's an internal/`private` function, I can make assumptions about the input. If it's not, I can't.

Comment: I placed I/O manipulators in your order and the code works correctly now. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @abalaev Great that it worked out! You're welcome! Note though: If `BYTE` is a _signed_ type, you will need an extra cast first. Is it a signed type or is it a `typedef` for `std::byte` or `unsigned char`?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `ostringstream`, you can always bake your own char to hex function:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string to_hex(char v) {
    static char hexd[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    char c[]{hexd[(v & 0xF0) >> 4], hexd[v & 0x0F]};
    return {c, c + 2};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> input{15, 78, 76, 32, 20};
    std::string s;
    for (auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it) {
        if (it != input.begin()) s += " ";
        s += "0x" + to_hex(*it);
    }

    assert(s == std::string("0x0F 0x4E 0x4C 0x20 0x14"));
}
```

Thanks to @TedLyngmo for edit suggestions.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++20` but I see the problem, I pasted wrong version of my code.  Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Great! You're welcome! Why are you creating a 5 `char` array in `to_hex`? Why not [2](https://godbolt.org/z/7hvndcrxn)?

Comment: Got me there, I quickly adapted to_hex() from a C function that had other purposes too.  I'll modify the function as you suggested.
By the way, do you think `constexpr` is makes any difference there?

Comment: Nah, I doubt `constexpr` makes a real diff here, but I like it for clarity.

Comment: Disassembly seems to be identical with and without.
Which string initialiser are you using in the return statement?  I thought the second argument is count, but are you passing iterators to it?

Comment: Okay, the return statement seems to be using form 6 from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: Yes, it's the ctor taking iterators.